# Racket: N Queens solving by column

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm new to Racket and as one of my first semi-complex programs I'm trying to solve the N queens problem by traversing linearly through column; so that the result would be a list (2 4 1 3), for example, where 2 is the 4th column, 2nd row, 4 is the 3rd column, 4th row, etc. My program currently is

```
#lang racket

(define (enumerate-interval l h)
  (if (> l h) '() (cons l (enumerate-interval (+ l 1) h))))

(define (iperm l a)
  (if (null? l) (list '()) (append-map (lambda (x)
                                  (map (lambda (p) (cons x p))
                                       (iperm (remove x l) (cons x a))))
                                l)))

(define (diagonal? col a)
  (cond
    ((null? a) #f)
    ((and (not (eq? col (+ (car a) (length a))))
          (not (eq? col (- (car a) (length a))))
          (diagonal? col (cdr a))) #f)
    (else #t)))

(define (iqueens l a)
  (if (null? l) (list '()) (append-map (lambda (x)
                                      (map (lambda (p) (cons x p))
                                           (if (diagonal? x a) 
                                               '()
                                               (iqueens (remove x l) (cons x a)))))
                                    l)))

(define (q n)
  (iqueens (enumerate-interval 1 n) '()))
```

I'd like it to return all solutions, or permutations that qualify when (q n) is called, n being the number of queens on the nxn board. My predicate diagonal? seems to be working. My problem is with the structure of iqueens. I want to return null when the partial permutation doesn't work to solve the problem, but as someone new to sequence programming, I'm not sure I know how I want to set it up.

Comment: Returning all the solutions requires covering all the search space because there is no known method to determine the number of solutions to `N-queens` based on the value of `n`. This doesn't mean that the search space cannot be pruned, but what cannot be pruned must be searched because there might be one or more solutions lurking within.

Comment: Commenting the code would be helpful.